# Did my kitten have a seizure?

Tags: cats, behavior, health, new-pets

We just brought home a kitten an hour ago and everything seemed to be fine. As I was crawling over towards it, it stopped and looked scared and started to shake. Its eyes were focused forward, but at nothing particular. After a few seconds its ears went back and started to twitch rapidly, and it started to drool from the side of its mouth. It was still standing on its four paws, and this lasted about 10 seconds before the cat returned to normal. A few meows and it was back to playing.

I'm worried this kitten had a seizure - it did have a stressful day of vet/vaccines/dewormer and a new house. Is it likely this was a seizure? If so, is it likely to recur? I'm wondering if I should take the kitten back.

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! Could you descripe the incident more in detail please? Until now I understand, that you scared the cat and it freeze in motion (standing on its paws?) with a little saliva dropping out of its mouth, right?

Comment: Correct, it froze and started to shake. It’s eyes we’re focused forward but at nothing particular. It’s ears went back and started to twitch rapidly. It began to drill from the side of its mouth but was over so fast it only dripped a small amount of saliva.

Comment: Were the ears "looking" in your direction as it "wents them back"?

Comment: Until now it sounds not like a seizure to me. Simple like a fear reaction of "wait without noise to see what happens next and be ready for a sprint out of reach". But I am not a cat-person, so maybe you wait for a more experienced one, or ask a vet, if you have worries about the health of your cat :)

Comment: Thanks! and ears were pointed away.

Answer (score -1):

According to [vcahospitals.com/know-your-pet/seizures-and-epilepsy-in-cats](https://vcahospitals.com/know-your-pet/seizures-and-epilepsy-in-cats#:%7E:text=termed%20idiopathic%20epilepsy.-,Idiopathic%20epilepsy%20is%20an%20inherited%20disorder%20in%20dogs%2C%20but%20is,disease%20within%20the%20brain%20itself.)

> Idiopathic epilepsy is an inherited disorder in dogs, but is rarely diagnosed in cats. In comparison to dogs, seizures and epilepsy are much less common in cats and are usually symptoms of disease within the brain itself.

In more basic terms:

Epilepsy is very uncommon in cats, maybe even rare. The only reason why a cat would have a seizure is if its brain was compromised with disease itself. If you aren't sure if the kitten had brain disease, check with your vet.